# C# Reflection Create Interface at Runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, runtime

Is there a way to create an Interface at runtime? I tried:

```
string typeSignature = "IFoo";
...
TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature, TypeAttributes.Interface);
```

But that gives an exception:

'Interface must be declared abstract.'

So I tried:

```
TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature, TypeAttributes.Interface 
    | TypeAttributes.Abstract);
Type dynamicType = tb.CreateType();
```

But `dynamicType.GetType().IsInterface` returns false. For some reason it thinks dynamicType is a class.

Comment: dynamicType.GetType() gets you the Type class. And Type is a class. You presumably wanted to check dynamicType.IsInterface.

Comment: And you presumably wanted your interface to be public. Private interfaces are pretty useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Ralf in the comment, you can try,

```
TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(
    typeSignature,
    TypeAttributes.Interface | TypeAttributes.Abstract | TypeAttributes.Public);
Type dynamicType = tb.CreateType();

dynamicType.IsInterface      // true
```