Error when it is dynamically created (run-time) a new interface type that inherits from another interface built on compilation-time
Given an interface build on compilation-time1 this:
    public interface Foo {} //[1] Interfaces created during the compilation.
    public interface FooA : Foo {} //[1] Interfaces created during the compilation.

When I try to create new instances using the classic reflection methods:
    public static Type CreateInterfaceType(string @namespace, string className, Type baseType)
    {
        var idName = "DynamicAssembly";
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(idName);
        var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(idName);
        var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType($"{@namespace}.{className}", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Interface,null, new[] { baseType} );
        return typeBuilder.CreateType();
    }

Always is thrown this error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Interface must be declared abstract.'
It is weird that interface must be typed as abstract.
I need that interface will be built in runtime (to use memory and runtime sounds very redundant) as interface instead other type because it will passed in runtime to generic method using hard reflection because you can not directtly pass it.
The problem is that after change and permute all modifier flags using only abstract or classes must be created in runtime but interfaces.
This is the list of modifiers that were permuted as part of the troubleshooting:
TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Interface
TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Abstract
TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class`

Any suggestions instance a dynamic interface type not a interface instance.

Solved in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485064/c-sharp-reflection-create-interface-at-runtime
